# Implement data access layer abstraction

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-access-layer

This may be a textbook question, but I'm considering how to design some classes that abstract the database connection away from a RESTful service that receives query results.

My thoughts are that to create a data access layer interface, then make a top level class that implements it and includes any operations that will be shared by all databases.  Then, I'd implement concrete subclasses of this superclass (an adapter).

Seems straightforward to me, but some people I've bounced this off believe it may be more complicated.

For context, this is Java and the two DB's are MySQL and HBase. We already have data access layer (DAL) classes for MySQL.  These don't use hibernate or spring; they construct db queries and create POJO instances from the results, manually.

So I guess my question has two parts:

> 1) is this as simple as I think?

and

> 2) is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

As it's the case with this kind of questions, the response can only be: it depends!

Based on what you are trying to achieve, [this can be a complicated issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) or can be a simpler one. You could go for a full fledged ORM tool like Hibernate or use a custom basic layer with low level JDBC constructs. It's whatever works for you given the kind of application you have.

But don't ignore the fact that what you want to do is basically a reinvention of the wheel. [This has been done before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Java). You should either reuse the DAL you have if it does its job well, or go for an existing framework.

At this point the implementation you want is just a matter of choosing the proper tool. Don't just blindly chose one, analyze advantages and disadvantages of each then select the best one for the job (either yours or others).

Comment: Just a personal preference, but also have a look at [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/)/[myBatis](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/)